# Will continent bonuses accumulate?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

In XCOM 2 (WotC), will the continent bonuses add up, if I get it more than once?

I don't think I've ever seen this before, but my current game I'm seeing "Integrated Warfare" show up twice.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any mods? I thought the integrated warfare bonus was from the Guerrilla  Tactics School, although it's possible WOTC changed this and I just didn't notice.

Comment: I am, but no mods that should have any bearing here. I'm pretty certain this was changed in WotC. I just don't recall ever seeing the same bonus appear twice.

Comment: Interesting. I would assume that this a modding-issue, because I never heard of this happening before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured I would try it. I can confirm, they *do not* accumulate.

Before:

[image]

Then capturing the Asia bonus:

[image]

After:

[image]

What I cannot say for sure is, if this condition is normal or if it was introduced by a bug or a mod. But the conclusion seems to be, if you end up like this for whatever reason, the bonuses are unique and they do not stack.

Comment: Pretty much what I would've suspected. From a coding perspective its probably just some if (continentBonusActive) {...} check.